# Saving tags with acts_as_taggable and activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, acts-as-taggable

I'm using ActiveAdmin and acts_as_taggable in a rails 3 app, and I can get the tag list to show fine as a checklist on edit pages, and I can add tags using the console and then *remove* them using the form, but it errors on saving the form if I try and add tags with

"Validation failed: Context can't be blank"

I only have one tagging context (tags).

ActiveAdmin form code is:

```
form    :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :title
        f.input :itinerary, :as => :select, :collection => Itinerary.all
        f.input :description
        f.input :address
        f.input :contact_details
        f.input :url
        f.input :phone
        f.input :nearest_tube
        f.input :timetable
        f.input :price
  f.input :tags, :as => :check_boxes, :multiple => true, :collection => @tags
        f.input :image, :as => :file
    end
    f.buttons
end
```

And in the model I have

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :itinerary
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "210x140>", :thumb => "100x100>" }  
end
```

If I add

```
  attr_writer :tag_ids
```

to the model, it no longer errors on saving, but still doesn't save the selected tags in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: Wondering if you ever solved this problem? i am running into the same thing or something similar. my problem is it is passing an ID rather than the name. and it is creating new tags with the name of the id i passed to it.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't use check boxes, but this worked well for me:

```
f.input :tag_list, :hint => 'Comma separated'
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from Nathan's answer, tag_list takes a list of tag names, so you can use checkboxes by passing a collection of tag names:

```
f.input :tag_list, :as => :check_boxes, 
  :collection => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.map(&:name)
```

Comment: could the checkboxed has the pre-checked function, if it already has the tag ?